# Script to filter incoming mail postfix centOS

Tags: postfix

I need run a custom ruby script to filter incoming mail on postfix.

In Ubuntu I use on master.cf

```
my_filter unix - n n - - pipe
  flags=Rq user=filter argv=/path/to/filter.rb ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=my_filter:dummy
```

My filter.rb

```
if approve_this_mail()
    `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t < #{@full_mail_source}`   
else
    ...
end
```

In centOS the command sendmail (i try with many flags) call the my_filter, so, enter in a loop.

Postfix Version: 2.10.1
CentOS 7.6

Comment: What are the versions of OS and programs used? What package is providing the sendmail common on both systems? Please provide more details, and compare configurations.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.5 with Ubuntu 3.1.0.